# How do I fix the error "Error: no valid exports main found" on windows 7

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, visual-studio-code, package.json

I am not able to run react app on my windows 7 OS. I have npm version 6.13.4, node version 13.6.0 installed.  It gives me the below error code when I do npm start.  I tried deleting the node module and did npm install again and tried to run but it still errors out.  Any idea how to get this solved?

```
Error: No valid exports main found for 'D:\practice\samplereact\test\node_modules\postcss-safe-parser\node_modules\postcss'
←[90m    at resolveExportsTarget (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:625:9)←[39m
←[90m    at applyExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:502:14)←[39m
←[90m    at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:22)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:960:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:855:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1033:19)←[39m
←[90m    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)←[39m
    at Object.<anonymous> 
(D:\practice\samplereact\test\node_modules\←[4mpostcss-safe-parser←[24m\lib\safe-parse.js:1:17)
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1144:30)←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m
```

i am trying to run the react app via VS code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Run `npm i --save` and if it's still not working add to your question your `package.json` file.

Comment: i tried npm i --save but still it is giving error

Comment: add to your question your package.json file.